# Holes on inner side of rim are off-center. Problem?

Tags: wheels, rims

I noticed that the holes on the tyre side of a rim are not centred. Some are more to the side, some less. The image below shows a hole that comes up all the way to the edge of the central channel on the tyre side of the rim. Please compare the hole position to the rim edges, not to the red rim tape, which is also not quite centred.

Is this a problem I should be worried about? Is it normal? Note that this rim is described as "tubeless compatible" by the bicycle manufacturer, although it does not come "tubeless ready".

This is a new bike. Is this a warranty issue?

[image]

Comment: I noticed this after getting the first flat after just over 2 weeks of use. There was a single hole on the _inside_ of the inner tube, not the outside as is more usual. I found no sharp object inside of the tyre. Could this be related?

Comment: The rim looks perfectly fine, although I would make sure to center that tape if I were you, and make sure it's wide enough to cover the holes

Comment: Who manufactured the wheel

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I understand the question well, what you are observing can be normal if you have asymmetric rims - this design is meant to decrease the tension different between non-drive and drive side spokes (your picture would be consistent with this explanation if it is the front wheel). The following drawing might help you:
[image]

More info: [Asymmetric wheel. Which side should the "asymmetry" be on?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/42912/asymmetric-wheel-which-side-should-the-asymmetry-be-on)

Comment: To dispel any remaining confusion, I'd add an image showing that the holes aren't necessarily drilled along the same line, whether that line is offset from the center or not, but that they can alternate sides from left to right. Something like https://spokecalc.io/img/articles/how-rim-designs-affect-spoke-length/alternating-spoke-offset-bed.jpg You probably understand this, but the OP might not know it. (Also my description is horrible.)

Comment: Wait... I thought you made a typo in your remark regarding front wheel, but perhaps I'm misunderstanding what you even meant. Can you clarify?

Comment: @leftaroundabout The "largest side" of rim is on the side where the spokes are the most vertical. On the rear wheel, it's the drive side. On the front wheel, it's the non-drive side (with the rotor) — don't make sense to have asymmetric rims with rim brakes in the front, as these wheels are symmetric. I meant that the explanation of the asymmetric rim would only explain the offset if the picture that is shown by the OP is the front wheel. If it's the picture of the rear wheel, my explanation is not consistent.

Comment: You are correct. The rims are asymmetric. Yes, this is the front wheel.

Answer (score 4):

As others have stated in their answers, the asymmetric placement of the spoke holes in the rim are normal and the wheel is fine.

More to answer this portion of your question: *Note that this rim is described as "tubeless compatible" by the bicycle manufacturer, although it does not come "tubeless ready".*

I have had some experience with trying to set up a similar (Giant P-SL0, circa 2015), tubeless compatible rim to run tubeless, and the asymmetric placement of the spoke holes in the bed of the rim posed problems with getting a good seal with the required tubeless rim tape, at least for me. Because one row of the spoke holes were close to where the edge of the tubeless rim tape would lie in the rim bed, it was more difficult to get it to seal enough and be durable enough to have confidence that the wheel would remain air-tight, even with sealant. In the end, I abandoned trying to get my asymmetric rim set up as tubeless and have since (for years now) have had success setting up symmetric spoked rims to run tubeless.

That was my experience, and the picture of your wheels showing how close the spoke holes are to the edge of the rim look similar to what I have. You may or may not have success in setting the wheel up tubeless, but be prepared for a struggle with the location of the spoke holes relative to the edge (you should not apply tape into the bead area of the wheel!). If you do attempt it, try it with the asymmetric rim first (only my rear rim was asymmetric - may not be the case with disc brake hubs nowadays). That way, you only invest the energy and time into the more challenging conversion first. If it works, great; proceed to the other wheel. If it doesn't, you are out less materials and time/energy.

Good luck, and if you are successful (or not), leave a comment on this answer so we all can learn.

Answer (score 3):

The spoke holes in your rim are quite normal! To quote [Sheldon Brown's wheelbuilding guide](https://www.sheldonbrown.com/wheelbuild.html):

> The spoke holes do not run down the middle of the rim, but are offset alternately from side to side. The holes on the left side of the rim are for spokes that run to the left flange of the hub.

Comment: When you say "spoke holes", do you refer to the holes where the spokes exit the rim, which are visible when the tyre is mounted? Those are indeed alternating. What I am showing here is on the other side, only visible when the tyre is removed. All the holes are offset towards the _same_ side, but some by more and some by less. They are not alternating. After looking at online pictures, it is clear that these are meant to be in the middle. My question is: how big a problem is it that they are not?

Comment: Correction: On this rim the spoke holes are not alternating. They are reasonably well centred. But my point was that I am not referring to the spoke holes. I think these are called access holes?

Comment: If you take the rim tape off you'll see the only thing in there is a nipple. Double-walled rims usually have this hole drilled for easy installation of the nipple. (Current Campagnolo rims, for example, don't have these holes.) The point is the drive side and non-DS holes can alternate left to right (i.e. drive side spokes/nipples are placed in holes that are closer to the drive side of the rim, and the opposite is true for the NDS spokes). The line across which the holes are symmetrical doesn't have to be in the center of the rim, as Renaud's answer shoes.